# Pronunciation of letters "g" and "c" in blend words

Tags: pronunciation, portmanteau-words

According to [this article](http://esl.about.com/od/speakingintermediate/a/hardsoftcg.htm):

> The Pronunciation of ‘C’ and ‘G’ generally (but not always) depends
>   upon the letter following either 'C' or 'G'. If the following letter
>   is ‘E’, ‘I’ or ‘Y’, the pronunciation is said to be “soft” (as in
>   *cell & large*). If the following letter is anything else - including a space - the pronunciation is termed “hard”. (as in *call & great*)

I'm wondering if these letters (‘C’ and ‘G’) retain their pronunciation in [blend words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend).
For example consider the word "**Regex**". This word is made from combining "**Regular**" and "**Expression**". How should the letter "g" in Regex be pronounced? Soft, like in "*General*"? or hard, like in "*Regular*"?

Comment: Those "rules" don't always apply. *Celt* and *girdle*, for example, have the "hard" pronunciations.

Comment: Bagel, auger, target, lager ... and I've never heard Regex pronounced with the hard g. Too "hard" to enunciate it that way, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "should" or prescriptive rule for pronunciation of unfamiliar words. What people do which resembles a rule is to apply common patterns, such as soft *g* before *e*, when a new word comes along.

As this new word circulates, you are likely to hear a lot of “rEH-jeks”, following the common pattern, but also a lot of “rEGG-ex”, after the word “rEGG-u-lar”. And eventually one will win the day. We'll just have to wait to see how it turns out.

Comment: No doubt you meant "such as *soft* g before e"?

Comment: Think about GIGO, which always has a *g* sound, not a *j* sound.